# Issue with uWSGI with Python3 (osx) in virtualenv

Tags: macos, python-3.x, flask, uwsgi

I can't get uWSGI to serve simple flask app. While in active virtualenv I run
`uwsgi --http :9090 -H .virtualenv/app --wsgi-file run.py`

`*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.8 (64bit) on [Sun Nov 16 15:29:48 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) on 14 November 2014 12:40:05
os: Darwin-13.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
nodename: myuser-MacBook-Pro.local
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: ~/repos/app
detected binary path: /Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/app/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 709
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 256
lock engine: OSX spinlocks
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :9090 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 39763)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:53849 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 17:52:17)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.51)]
Set PythonHome to /Users/myuser/.virtualenv/app
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Abort trap: 6`

Looks like this line is the main issue `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec`. Thanks in advance on any input on this matter.

Comment: ensure the virtualenv has been created for python3.4

Comment: @roberto yes env was created for python3

Comment: Running into this problem while trying to follow [this tutorial using Python3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)